# Função click do link não é chamada

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

Já tive um problema semelhante a esse, e erá por causa da função ser contruida antes da criação do botão. Agora fiz tertinho depois de eu dar um append na minha pagina chamo um função on click.

Esse é meu codigo no codepen: [link](http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/BKoBKJ)

Para você entenderem a ideia é que a pessoa click no botões pretos para adicionar campos do tipo desejado, eles setam o nome do campo e label na div do meio, e na terceira div é mostrado como esta formulário.

O que acontece é que quero poder remover um campo clicando no botão azul, o problema é que não é chamado esse trecho:

```
$('#remove_input').on("click", function() {
  var count_field = $('#count_field').val();
  var parent_class = $(this).parents('tr');
  if (parent_class.hasClass('pending')) {
    parent_class.remove();
    count_field--;
  } else if(parent_class.hasClass('saved')) {
    parent_class.removeClass('saved').addClass('remove');
  }
  $('#count_field').val(count_field);
});
```

este codigo esta dentro da função de click no botão de add logo apos eu fazer um append do novo campo.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Só para deixar claro o campo address que vem já no html esta com o funcionamento correto que é apenas deixar o botão vermelho. O problema esta no campo adicionado posteriormente, pelo botão add.

Comment: Seu problema provavelmente é porque essas coisas são dinâmicas. Ao criar os botões tu pode copiar uma tag que está hidden, ou você faz um `bind` passando o evento do click pro botão pra ele funcionar. É só chute, mas creio eu que seja isso.

Comment: @DH você poderia dar um exemplo com o bind?

Answer (score 0):

Veja se assim dar certo.

```
$('#remove_input').click(function() {
    var count_field = $('#count_field').val();
    var parent_class = $(this).parents('tr');
    if (parent_class.hasClass('pending')) {
    parent_class.remove();
    count_field--;
    } else if(parent_class.hasClass('saved')) {
    parent_class.removeClass('saved').addClass('remove');
    }
    $('#count_field').val(count_field);
});
```

> User o firebug para ver se está passando ou se esta gerando erro.

Comment: Cara já tentei assim e não de certo também, você testou no codeopen? Se sim me manda o link de um fork.

Comment: No firebug mostra que ele nunca chama essa parte do codigo